# Symfony2 - how to register external library (tiktalik)?

Tags: symfony

how to register external library Tikalik http://c.tiktalik.com/SDK/PHP/sdk-1.5.10.tar.gz
 in Symfony 2.7 and use like below?

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function testTiktalikAction() {
      $s3 = new \TiktalikFiles(); //external
    }

}
```

Comment: Install it with composer if you can.  If not, adjust app/autoload.php to pick it up.

Comment: I don't know how to pick it up with autoload. Can you help me? Tiktalik is placed in vendor/tiktalik/src/. My autoload looks like this: $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
return $loader;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_include_path` method in app/autoload.php.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.realpath(__DIR__.'/../vendor/tiktalik/src'));
```

Set include path above the line where loader is required from vendor/autoload.php